# How can I properly read data from bar code scanner?

Tags: c++, libusb-1.0

I am working on project which aims at saving articles information on database. To do so, I implement a dialog box (using wxWidgets c++) that allows to enter information about an article. When the user scan the bar code of a given article, my app should read the data from the bar code and display it on a text control. To read data, I use **libusb 1.0** library which provides a lot of routines to handle an usb device. To poll data from bar code scanner I implement a function that handle a timer event and in which i put a code to read data. Unfortunately, up to there, I am not able to read data from bar code scanner. Please find below my code.

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <libusb.h>
#include <ioSerialPort\SerialPort.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::assign; 



SerialPort::SerialPort()
: _session(NULL)
, _targetDevices()
{
    init();
}

void SerialPort::init()
{
    libusb_device **devs = NULL; 
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL; 
    libusb_device_handle *barCodeScannerHandle = NULL;
    uint8_t barCodeScannerEndPointIn;
    ssize_t cnt; 
    r = libusb_init(&_session); 

    libusb_set_debug(_session, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation
    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(_session, &devs); //get the list of devices

    ///Find target device
    libusb_device* barCodeScanner = findDevice(devs, cnt, 0x5050, 0x24);

    if ( barCodeScanner != NULL )
    {
        barCodeScannerHandle = open(barCodeScanner);
        barCodeScannerEndPointIn = getDeviceInEndpoint(barCodeScanner);
    }
    _targetDevices += DeviceInfos(*barCodeScanner, *barCodeScannerHandle, barCodeScannerEndPointIn);

    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, unref the devices in it
}

libusb_device* SerialPort::findDevice(libusb_device **devices,int deviceNum, uint16_t VID, uint16_t PID)
{
    assert( _session != NULL);
    for(int iDevice = 0; iDevice < deviceNum; iDevice++ )
    {
        libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(devices[iDevice], &desc);
        if( r >= 0 && desc.idVendor == VID && desc.iProduct == PID)
        {
            return devices[iDevice];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

libusb_device_handle* SerialPort::open( libusb_device* device) const
{
    assert( device != NULL );

    libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
    libusb_open(device, &handle);
    return handle;
}

uint8_t SerialPort::getDeviceInEndpoint(libusb_device* device)
{
    uint8_t inEndpoint = 0;
    libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
    libusb_config_descriptor *config;
    libusb_get_config_descriptor(device, 0, &config);
    const libusb_interface *inter;
    const libusb_interface_descriptor *interdesc;
    inter = &config->interface[0];
    interdesc = &inter->altsetting[0];
    for(int iEndPoint = 0; iEndPoint < interdesc->bNumEndpoints; iEndPoint++)
    {
        if( interdesc->endpoint[iEndPoint].bEndpointAddress & LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN)
        {
            inEndpoint =  interdesc->endpoint[iEndPoint].bEndpointAddress;
        }

    }
    libusb_free_config_descriptor(config);
    return inEndpoint;
}

/// This is the method that I use when catching the timer event
string SerialPort::readDataFromDevice()
{
    int bytes_received;
    string data;


    int result = 0;

    DeviceInfos deviceInfos = _targetDevices.back();
    libusb_device_handle* handle = deviceInfos._handle;
    uint8_t inEndPoint = deviceInfos._endPoint;


    int DATA_MAX_SIZE =  libusb_get_max_packet_size(deviceInfos._device, inEndPoint);
    unsigned char data_in[8];
    int actualData;
    if( handle != NULL)
    {
        if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(handle, 0) == 1) 
        {
            int r = libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0); //detach it
        }

        if( libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0) == 0) 
        {
            bytes_received = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, inEndPoint, data_in, DATA_MAX_SIZE, &actualData, 0);
        }

        if( bytes_received > -1)
        {
            data = reinterpret_cast<char*> (data_in);
        }
        int r = libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    }
    return data;
}



SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    libusb_exit(_session); //close the session
}
```

The function "libusb_bulk_transfer" always return -1. Please help me!

Comment: Maybe you should try and find out *why* `libusb_bulk_transfer` fails? Does it set `errno`? Or is there some other libusb function to get the error?

Comment: A barcode scanner typically simulates key presses and prints the number as if a person typed it on the keyboard. Doesn't that work for you? It would work out-of-the-box with no programming required

Comment: @Alex Acting as a keyboard wedge might be the way you're used to working with scanners, but not all can be configured that way, and even if they can be, there are reasons to avoid it. One issue is having to worry about where keyboard focus is, and whether characters incoming are from the scanner or something else. Moving the source of the barcode characters to another transport than the keyboard is usually desired.

Comment: I aggree with Steve because I want to handle data coming from my barcode scanner. Joachim, errno return 9 which means "Bad file number". I don't know what does it mean. Tanks you for help!